# calculating triangle coordinates from 3 lengths and its euler rotation in 3d space

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have the following situation:

I have three constant points: $P_1(a_1, b_1, 0), P_2(a_2, b_2, 0), P_3(a_3, b_3, 0)$. These points are on a cartesian 3d space and form an equilateral triangle with a side length equal to `len1`.

I also have a second equilateral triangle let's call it $T$ (in the same 3d space) with a side length equal to `len2 < len1` defined by three points $T_1(x_1, y_1, z_1), T_2(x_2, y_2, z_2), T_3(x_3, y_3, z_3)$ and a constraint: $z_1, z_2, z_3 > 0$. $len2$ is known.

The last known thing are 3 Euler angles: $θ_x, θ_y, θ_z$ which represent the rotation of triangle $Τ$ in the 3d space, $θ_x$ is the rotation of triangle $T$ in the $x$ axis and so on. Constraint: $-90 < θ_x, θ_y, θ_z < 90$ degrees.

The winding order of the triangle is the same, i.e. always $T_1,T_2,T_3$, not possible to have $T_3, T_1, T_2$ or other combinations. The minimum angle of the face normal of triangle $T$ with plane $z=0$ is $>0$ degrees. Just mentioning this to avoid situations like placing the triangle face down.

My first question is:

**For all possible values of $(x_1, y_1, z_1), (x_2, y_2, z_2), (x_3, y_3, z_3)$, i.e. for all possible positions of triangle $T$ with side length =`len2` and $z>0$ on a given rotation of the triangle $T$: $θ_x, θ_y, θ_z$, is there a unique vector $(L_1, L_2, L_3)$ where $L_1 = Dist(P_1, T_1), L_2 = Dist(P_2, T_2), L_3 = Dist(P_3, T_3)$ ?**

My second question is:

**If the answer to the previous question is yes, then given $L_1, L_2, L_3$ and the rotation $θ_x, θ_y, θ_z$ of triangle $Τ$, what are the equations for finding the coordinates of the three points $T_1, T_2, T_3$ of triangle $T$?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The answer to your first question is no.  Because you can place triangle $T$ anywhere you want on the plane, so of course the lengths $L_1, L_2, L_3$ are not unique.

Comment: @Potato maybe you misunderstood: lengths L1, L2, L3 are constant. Given. let's say L1=23,L2=15,L3=10. and the plane has inclination: θχ=15deg, θy=10deg, θz=5deg

Comment: @Potato may I ask why you deleted your answer?

Comment: "The minimum angle of the face normal of triangle $T$ with plane $z=0$ is $>0$ degrees." Minimum angle with respect to what? I would have expected the angle to be relative to the $z$ basis vector (which is also taken as the face normal of the first triangle), so the angle $\pi > 0$ is upside down, and the "right side up" condition is that the angle is less than $\pi/2$ radians.

Comment: I don't know how you construct a case like "θχ=15deg, θy=10deg, θz=5deg". Are those Euler angles of some kind? Inclination of a plane should only require two angles.

Comment: @DavidK I have edited my question, I messed it up in my head, yes those 3 are Euler angles and represent the rotation of triangle $T$ in the 3D space.

Comment: @DavidK minimum angle in respect to the x axis, what I mean there is that the face normal of triangle $T$ cannot "look" downward, in worst case scenario it will be parallel to $x$ axis.

Comment: The triangle $T$ is rotated regarding what initial configuration?

Comment: @Cesareo $θx, θz$ are the angles/rotations regarding $x$ and $z$ axis respectively, which means they define the inclination of the plane that triangle $T$ is. $θy$ is the angle/rotation regarding the $y$ axis, which means rotation around the face normal vector of the plane, I guess. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/3D_coordinate_system.svg/2048px-3D_coordinate_system.svg.png

Comment: @Cesareo So those three angles are pitch, yaw, roll. Trying to put it in those terms if it makes more clear what I'm trying to say.

Comment: My question is concerning the initial $T$ configuration, before the rotation.

Comment: @Cesareo I'm not sure I understand what do you mean by "initial configuration"

Comment: The given triangle $T_1(x_1, y_1, z_1), T_2(x_2, y_2, z_2), T_3(x_3, y_3, z_3)$ is previous to the rotation or after it?

Comment: @Cesareo after. I'm looking to find those coordinates of $T1, T2, T3$ and the only information I have is $θx, θy, θz$ and the lengths $L1, L2, L3$

Comment: @Cesareo $len2$ is also known, in case that I did not make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any transformation is decomposable into translation, deformation (here only isotropic deformation is present, due to equilaterality) and rotation. Rotation is done by three subsequent rotations with respect to 3 different axes, where the transformation order matters. The triangle after transformation is given by formula:
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{c}x_i\\y_i\\z_i\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}X_0\\Y_0\\Z_0\end{array}\right]+
\underbrace{\frac{\text{len}_2}{\text{len}_1}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 
c_3  & s_3 & 0 \\
-s_3 & c_3 & 0 \\
0    & 0   & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 
c_2  & 0 & s_2 \\
0    & 1 & 0   \\
-s_2 & 0 & c_2 \\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 
1    & 0 & 0 \\
0 & c_1  & s_1   \\
0 & -s_1 & c_1   \\
\end{array}\right]}_{\mathbf{A}}
\left[\begin{array}{c}a_i\\b_i\\0\end{array}\right],~~i=1,2,3,
\end{align}
where $\text{len}_2<\text{len}_1,~z_i>0,~c_i=\cos(\theta_i),~s_i=\sin(\theta_i),~i=1,2,3$, $~\theta_1=\theta_x,~\theta_2=\theta_y,~\theta_3=\theta_z$, where matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is known and where the vector $[X_0,~Y_0,~Z_0]^{\text{T}}$ represents translation.

Continuation:

Moreover we have known distances $L_1,L_2,L_3$ so that we want
\begin{align}
&(x_i-a_i)^2+(y_i-b_i)^2+z_i^2=L_i^2,~~i=1,2,3,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&z_i>0,~~i=1,2,3.
\end{align}
Also we have 12 equations
\begin{align}
&\left[\begin{array}{c}x_i\\y_i\\z_i\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}X_0\\Y_0\\Z_0\end{array}\right]+
\mathbf{A}\left[\begin{array}{c}a_i\\b_i\\0\end{array}\right],~~i=1,2,3,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)\\
&(x_i-a_i)^2+(y_i-b_i)^2+z_i^2=L_i^2,~~i=1,2,3,~~~~~~(2)\\
\end{align}
for 12 unknowns $X_0,Y_0,Z_0,$ $x_i,y_i,z_i,i=1,2,3$. So we can hope, at least in some cases, in a unique solution. If this solution satisfies $z_i>0,~i=1,2,3$ then we are done. The following is however clear:

1. There are such input parameters, that problem (1,2) has no solution
2. In case $\text{len}_2=\text{len}_1$ there are such input parameters, that problem (1,2) has infinitely many solutions

**Proof**: 1. for $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{0},~L_1=L_2=L_3=0$ and different points $P_1,~P_2,~P_3$ the problem definitely has no solution. 2. for $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{I},~L_1=L_2=L_3=1$ we see that for any $X_0,Y_0,Z_0$ s.t. $X_0^2+Y_0^2+Z_0^2=1$ we get solution, which satifies Eq.(2), ergo we have infinitely many different nontrivial solutions in this case. $\clubsuit$

**Remark (uniqueness in case len2<len1)**: If we insert Eqs.(1) into Eqs.(2) we can solve instead of 12 equations only 3 nonlinear equations:
\begin{align}
&(X_0+(a_{11}-1)a_i+a_{12}b_i)^2+(Y_0+a_{21}a_i+(a_{22}-1)b_i)^2+\\&(Z_0+a_{31}a_i+a_{32}b_i)^2=L_i^2,~~i=1,2,3.~~~~~~(3)\\
\end{align}
This is a problem of intersection of three spheres in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which has in general $0,1,2$ solutions (infinite number of solutions are not possible in case len2<len1). If we can proof, that in case of 2 different solutions one yields negative values of $z_i$ (which is indicated by all numerical solutions, which I have tried), then the proof of uniqueness is made. $\diamondsuit$

Comment: I am given a triangle in 3D space, for which I must find its location, i.e. the coordinates of its three vertices ($T1, T2, T3$). The only things I know are: distances $L1, L2, L3$ of its vertices from three points $P1, P2, P3$ and I also know the pitch/yaw/roll ($θx, θy, θz$) of the triangle. I am not sure what you have written solves my problem.

Comment: So you know points $P1, P2, P3$ and len$_1$. And len$_2$ is unknown, right?

Comment: I know points $P1, P2, P3$ and both $len1$ and $len2$ are known. Also known are $θx, θy, θz$

Comment: Thank you. I have one question: what do $X_0, Y_0, Z_0$ represent?

Comment: Translation of the triangle.

Comment: I read your note, not sure what $I$ is (possibly Identity table). I know I'm probably asking too much, is there a way for me to somehow visualize or "see" two such non unique cases where there are infinite solutions like in L1=L2=L3=1?

Comment: $\mathbf{I}$ is the $3\times3$ identity matrix. Example: $L_1=L_2=L_3=1$, $P_1=[1,0,0],~P_2=[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0],~P_3=[-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0]$, first triangle: $T_1=P_1+[0,0,1],~T_2=P_2+[0,0,1],~T_3=P_3+[0,0,1]$, second triangle $T_1=P_1+[0,1,0],~T_2=P_2+[0,1,0],~T_3=P_3+[0,1,0]$.

Comment: In this example, the first triangle is triangle $P$ translated/moved in the $z$ axis by one. it has the same side length $len2=len1$ [though it should be smaller (len2<len1)]  as triangle $P$ but let's say this is not a problem. The second example, is the same $P$ triangle translated/moved in the $y$ axis by one. Probably my mistake not to mention it because I just assumed it, but $z_i$ for triangle $T$ are always positive, meaning it's always "above" the $z=0$ plane. Does this mean the solutions are unique? or doesn't change anything?

Comment: I see now I have already mentioned in my first post that $z1, z2, z3$ are positive. So the second triangle of the example is not a duplicate solution.

Comment: The nonzero $z$ is not the issue, i can take the second triangle as $T_1=P_1+[0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}],~T_2=P_2+[0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}],~T_3=P_3+[0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]$. However I have considered here $len2=len1$.  For the case $len2<len1$ I have now no example of nonuniqueness in my mind.

Comment: but it still doesn't change anything, right? I mean, does the fact that $len2 < len1$ change the nonuniqueness into uniqueness?

Comment: If len2<len1 (I have overseen this condition), then it is not clear whether it is unique or not.

Comment: yes, len2 < len1 always. hm

Comment: btw about the question you asked me, did you see my reply?

Comment: no, was it in that chat? could you send me link again, i cannot find it. I have added also some remark about uniqueness to the answer for the case len2<len1.

Comment: yes it was in the chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131942/discussion-between-mirrormirror-and-vitzslav-stembera

Comment: thank you. Those $A_{11}, A_{32}$ etc. what matrices are they?

Comment: I meant by $A_{11}$ a component of matrix $A$. I used big numbers, not to confuse it with $a$, but it is possibly better to use small numbers instead, because two indices make the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Rotating the vector $\vec u$ for $\theta$ regarding a direction $\vec v$ with $\|\vec u\|=1,\|\vec v\|=1$ and $\vec u\cdot\vec v = 0$ we can build an equilateral triangle using the Rodrigues formula

$$
\vec u_{\theta} = R(\vec v,\theta)\cdot \vec u = \vec u\cos(\theta)+\vec v\times\vec u\sin(\theta)+\vec v\cdot\vec u(1-\cos(\theta))\vec v
$$

so giving a vertex $r_1\vec u$ we can construct the other two as follows

$$
T(\theta_1,r_1,\vec u,\vec v,\vec o) = \vec o+r_1\left(R\left(\vec v,\theta_1\right)\cdot\vec u,R\left(\vec v,\theta_1+\frac 23\pi\right)\cdot \vec u,R\left(\vec v,\theta_1+\frac 43\pi\right)\cdot \vec u\right)
$$

Here $\vec o$ represents the triangle's barycenter. This triangle is submitted to a Euler matrix $E(\alpha_0,\beta_0,\gamma_0)$ rotation as follows

$$
E(\alpha_0,\beta_0,\gamma_0)\cdot T(\theta_1,r_1,\vec u,\vec v,\vec o) = \mathbb{T}(\theta_1,r_1,\vec u,\vec v,\vec o) 
$$

Now giving a known triangle $T_0(\psi_0,r_2,\vec u_0,\hat{e}_z,\vec o_0)$ with $\psi_0,r_2$ given and $\hat{e}_z=(0,0,1),\vec u_0 = (1,0,0),\vec o_0=(1,1,0)$ we can define as objective function

$$
\mathcal{O}\left(\theta_1,\vec u,\vec v,\vec o\right)=\sum_k \|\|\mathbb{T}(\theta_1,r_1,\vec u,\vec v,\vec o)-T_0(\psi_0,r_2,\vec u_0,\hat{e}_z,\vec o_0)\|_k-\delta_k\|
$$

Here $\delta_k$ is given and the $\|\cdot\|_k$ is taken at each corresponding vertex in the triangles.

Finally, the determination of $T(\theta_1,r_1,\vec u,\vec v,\vec o)$ can be handled by solving the minimization problem

$$
\min_{\theta_1,\vec u,\vec v,\vec o}\mathcal{O}\left(\theta_1,\vec u,\vec v,\vec o\right)\ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ \cases{\|\vec u\|=1\\
\|\vec v\|=1\\
\vec u\cdot\vec v = 0\\
\mathbb{T}(\theta_1,r_1,\vec u,\vec v,\vec o)_k\cdot\hat{e}_z\ge 0}
$$

Depending on the values for $\alpha_0,\beta_0,\gamma_0$ the problem my not have solution or have non unique solutions.

Follows a case study with two solutions depicted in the attached graphic

[image]

NOTE

Here in green the triangle $T_0$ with $\psi_0 = 0,r_2 = 13,\hat{e}_z=(0,0,1),\vec u_0 = (1,0,0),\vec o_0=(1,1,0)$ and $\delta = (41.79, 27.6849, 44.9287)$ and for the rotation $\alpha_0 = 0.349093,\beta_0=-0.613477,\gamma_0=-0.0460201$ we have compatibility with the two solutions $r_1 = 10, \cases{\theta_1 =\frac{\pi}{4}, \vec u =(1,0,-1)/\sqrt{2}, \vec v = (1,1,1)/\sqrt{3},\vec o = (20,30,10)\\
\theta_1 = -3.0919,\vec u = (0.0914184,-0.550551,0.829781), \vec v = (0.76595,0.571371,0.294713),\vec o = (18.24,32.1887,2.45912)
}$

In red are the two versions of $T_1$ and in blue the rotated versions.

Comment: there are non unique solutions? So, @Vítězslav Štembera answer is wrong?

Comment: @MirrorMirror    Please. See attached note.

Comment: from what I can see in the graphic, both red and both blue triangles seem to be in different planes each which are not even parallel to each other, so how are the solutions non unique? Non-unique solutions would be two triangles $T1$ and $T2$ possibly on different planes (but still those planes would be parallel to each other, since $θx, θy, θz$ is known) AND having the same $L1, L2 ,L3$ (distances of their vertices from points $P1, P2, P3$).

Comment: I have checked my solution and the statement about uniqueness was really not correctly argued so I took it out. Thanx for that! However, the solution presented here does not solve the prescribed problem in my view, because $L1, L2, L3$ (here denoted by $\delta_k$) are minimized, but there are according to MirrorMirros's comment given. I have numerically checked the numerical solution presented here, and T1-T0={35.769919109; 30.874709718; 46.612035831} and T2-T0={37.531158587; 31.033214854; 45.660509178} i.e. they are different and therefore not solutions in the sense of my answer.

Comment: @VítězslavŠtembera Here $\delta =(L_1,L_2,L_3) = (41.79, 27.6849, 44.9287)$. In both solution triangles is the same.

Comment: In my view $\mathcal{O}$ should be identically $0$ and it is not.

Comment: Here $\mathcal{O} \approx 10^{-6} $. It fits well for practical purposes .

Comment: @VítězslavŠtembera it is obvious to me that both you guys math skills are way higher than mine, So I'm not sure I comprehend your comments. So you guys say it's possible that for given $P1, P2, P3$, $L1, L2, L3$ and given  $θx, θy, θz$ to have two different $T1, T2$ where the planes $PL1, PL2$ of those triangles are parallel to each other?

Comment: Yes. I have added some comment about this to my answer. We both agree now that the solution is not unique.

Comment: Comment to T1, T2 solutions given here: 1) normal vectors of both triangles are different, which is not correct, 2) I have calculated $\mathcal{O}$ and I got much higher values, there is some difference between our codes. I report my results here: T0: {[14.000000,1.000000,0.000000],[-5.500000,12.258330,0.000000],[-5.500000,-10.258330,0.000000]}
normal vector = [0.000000,0.000000,1.000000]
T1: {[22.113249,35.773503,2.113249],[12.113249,32.113249,15.773503],[25.773503,22.113249,12.113249]}
normal vector = [0.577350,0.577350,0.577350]

Comment: T1: {[22.113249,35.773503,2.113249],[12.113249,32.113249,15.773503],[25.773503,22.113249,12.113249]}
normal vector = [0.577350,0.577350,0.577350]
T2: {[17.010847,37.989733,-5.593036],[13.389603,34.315722,10.941422],[24.319551,24.260645,2.028975]}
normal vector = [0.765950,0.571371,0.294713]
Point difference (T1) = [35.769919,30.874710,46.612036]
Point difference (T2) = [37.531155,31.033214,45.660508]
O(T1) = 7.017826
O(T2) = 5.466672